# Geofence exit notification is being triggered while the device is still in that particular geofence

Tags: android

I have integrated Geofences in my application. 
 I have set radius as 100m, added entry and exit transition types, getting my events into an IntentService. 
 It is inconsistent. Sometimes the geofence is exiting from the location while the device is still in that geofence.

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you manage to find out why? I have the same issue at the moment.

Comment: I have and am still experiencing the same issue.  I wonder if this is a known issue at Google.

Comment: Any solutions regarding this issue ?. I am also facing it

Comment: Geofence exit because of multiple reasons like poor GPS or Wifi disconnect etc.,, so am checking if this is the real exit by querying the GPS location. If its not a real exit, am creating the geofence again.

Comment: @Chamu I'getting same issue but strange my location is only changed automatically  . it is showing in Google Maps 15km away from current location. What may be the problem, for that i'am getting exit event even i am inside. any clue ?